# cURL : Proxy Server getting target image

Tags: php, curl

I need some help. In creating a simple proxy server using this curl function.

```
$ch = curl_init($IP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: $HOSTNAME'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

it can redirects to the other server but it does change the links, like to target an image, what function should i need to add? thank you.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean to say is if the final link has an img then it is not changing the url inside "src" attribute. That is not possible in curl. What you need to do for that is parse the html and the manually change the links so that they are directed from your proxy server.

Also for creating a proxy server, you don't use host. You should fetch the contents using curl and print it out. What you are doing is a redirect and not a proxy

**Edit**

*Sample code for the proxy*

```
<?php
    $host = "1.1.1.1"; //This is the host
    $url = $host.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    echo file_get_contents($url);
    var_dump($http_response_header); //For debugging
?>
```

Because you are only making http request i think file_get_contents is a better suited function. Also the var_dump will give you response headers from the "1.1.1.1" ip.
Now a little note here. Have a look at content-type . This is important for images. Because browser needs to know the content type of the response. So what you need to do is parse the http_response_headers and then check for content-type and add headers in your response using *header()* function accordingly.

Hope this helps you better

Comment: i have this target site test1.com with ip 1.1.1.1 , i can access the content using my proxy script domain test2.com but it did not get the images, sample. test1.com/img/1.jpg it gives the image , but in test2.com/img/1.jpg it give an Not Found .

Comment: @rkevx21 you don't have a proper proxy then. You need to make sure that ALL requests proxy test1.

Comment: Okay let me add a sample script for you in my answer. :)

Comment: ah .. okay, can i have it? :) thank you sir. i'll check and test your script, its a big help  :)

Comment: @rkevx21 Check out the code. Also in case of file_get_contents , you can use curl. But i prefer this function because it is lesser typing for me :)

Comment: can you send it in my email sir?

Comment: Just copy from above :) i will be sending the same code.

Comment: as i add to var_dump($url); it gives me this result -> float(1.1) NULL

Comment: My bad bug in code. check now. Instead of concatinating the string i was adding them

Comment: what does it mean if var_dump($http_response_header); result is NULL ?

Comment: as i vardump $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , the result is string(1) "/"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108802/discussion-between-georoot-and-rkevx21).